# Can't upload objects to S3 using AWS SDK PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I installed the SDK via composer and have my creds in .aws/credentials. When running 'php PutObject.php' I get no output nor error/exception but the objects are not uploaded either. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. What's odd is I have the exact same config installed in my Mac and I can put objects.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;


// Create an S3 client
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'region'  => 'us-east-1',
'version' => 'latest',
'debug'   => true
]);

// Where the files will be source from
$source = 'TestUnit';

// Where the files will be transferred to
$dest = 's3://mybucket/TestUnit';

// Create a transfer object.
$manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($client, $source, $dest);

// Perform the transfer synchronously.
$manager->transfer();
```

Comment: Can you write the complete response you get from AWS

Comment: There is no response from the script, no exceptions thrown and nothing from S3 log. As a test, I tried putting the wrong creds in my credentials.ini and still no error. That tells me that it's not even being read. However, since there is no error thrown I've no idea what's really happening.

Comment: is the exception handled correctly ....normally it is used Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception; refer the basic s3 upload example http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html